# Angular Material how to vertical align md-button

Tags: css, angular-material

I am new to angular material. Below is my simple code.

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
    <md-button ng-click='toggleSideNav()'><md-icon md-svg-icon='menu'></md-icon></md-button>
    <div><div><img src='/Content/Images/logo.png' title='logo' alt='logo'></div></div> <!-- 138 * 66 image -->
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how to align the menu button vertically in the middle of the image on the left side? Something similar to the menu icon to left https://www.youtube.com/

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Actually Material aligns it for you. The season it's not aligned properly is because you put the image in div.

When you remove the double div it's in, it's aligned perfectly. If for some reason you need to keep these div, just make them the same height as your picture.

I just added this:

```
 div{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

to see the problem.

[image]

Comment: @the person who downvoted, can you explain why? I'd like to know what I missed/did wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It is hard to guess requirements from your example, but one of the solutions could this:

HTML:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center" layout-margin>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click='toggleSideNav()'>Test</md-button>
    <div >
      <img src="/Content/Images/logo.png" title='logo' alt='logo'>
    </div> <!-- 138 * 66 image -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  margin-left: -112px
}
```

Here is a playground: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjZEzb

Comment: Doesn't solved their problem tho, since it's most likely because of the div not matching the image height, hence making it seem badly aligned. In your playground removing the part " layout-align="start center" " doesn't actually change anything...